# Get pixel value from BITMAP file

Tags: bitmap, mfc, pixel, coordinate

I use VS2010 MFC.

I want to do following steps.

1. Load Bitmap file(640x480, 8bit).
2. Set coordinate. (x,y)
3. Get pixel value from coordinate (0~255).

But I don't know steps...

Please advise me :)

Comment: Do want to do this on a visible bitmap or should this be done just silently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should works:

```
#include "atlimage.h" // This is neccesary to use CImage objects from GDI+

void dummy ()
{
    std::string bitmapFile = "file.bmp"; // Full path of your bitmap file
    int x = 0; // Your x coordinate
    int y = 0; // Your y coordinate

    CImage image;
    if ( SUCCEEDED ( image.Load ( bitmapFile.c_str() ) ) )
    {
        COLORREF color = image.GetPixel ( x, y );
    }
}
```